# Library for FFT interpolation from values at arbitrary points

Tags: cryptography

I'm trying to implement a cryptographic scheme that leverages *constant-sized polynomial commitments* by Kate et al [[1]](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-17373-8_11).

I'm looking for a library that can interpolate a polynomial fast via FFT  in a finite field, but from values at arbitrary points (i.e., not roots of unity). A technique for doing this in `O(n log^2(n))` time for `n` points is described in ["Fast evaluation and interpolation," by
H. T. Kung](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~htk/publication/1973-cmu-cs-technical-report-kung.pdf).

I'm aware of:

- SCIPIR lab's [libfqfft](https://github.com/scipr-lab/libfqfft)
- [FLINT](http://www.flintlib.org/features.html)
- [NTL](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/)

...but AFAICT none of them seem to support interpolation from values at arbitrary  points.